# Getting all subsets within a data frame and listing all factors in R

Tags: r, subset

I am faced with a problem in R that involves subsets. I have to make a list of all the unique factors within a subset in R but I have been doing it via **for loop**.

For example, I have a data frame below:

```
       area         family    
 [1,] "Location 1" "Diaz"    
 [2,] "Location 1" "Santiago"
 [3,] "Location 2" "Peralta" 
 [4,] "Location 2" "Perez"   
 [5,] "Location 2" "Cooper"  
 [6,] "Location 3" "Tesla"   
 [7,] "Location 3" "Tatum"   
 [8,] "Location 4" "Brown"   
 [9,] "Location 4" "Lee"     
 [10,] "Location 4" "Anthony"
```

What I need for an output is below:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Diaz" "Santiago"

[[2]]
[1] "Peralta" "Perez" "Cooper"

[[3]]
[1] "Tesla" "Tatum"

[[4]]
[1] "Brown" "Lee" "Anthony"
```

Can anyone help me in simplifying this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` to split the 'family' column by the 'area' column in to `list` of `vector`s

```
split(df[,'family'], df[, 'area'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, consider `by`:

```
by(df, df[, "area"], function(x) x[,"family"])
```